# How can I pass non-static variables to the main method?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, static, swingworker

I have a problem with Java. I am trying to pass an `integer` based `Vector` to the main of the program. The problem is that the vector cannot be `static` as it contains values ​​that the program modifies.

How can I have the vector in `main` method?

This vector is used to send activation states via serial to an Arduino.

```
public int [] vector(){
    SwingWorker<int [], Integer> swingWorker1 = new SwingWorker<int [], Integer>(){
        @Override
        public int [] doInBackground()throws IOException, InterruptedException{
     int[] vec={manu,scarico,carico,co2,neon,led,res,filtro,g_luci,aria,uv,intera,decimale};  //initializing array  
   return vec;  
}
        
    };swingWorker1.execute();
    
    return null;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingWorker<Void, Integer> swingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>(){
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground()throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            while(true){
                int a;
                int []vec= new int[13] ;
                int []ric= new int [4] ;
                 JFrameAcquario jfk = new JFrameAcquario();
                 vec =jfk.vector();
                SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM3"); // device name TODO: must be changed
                sp.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0); // default connection settings for Arduino
                sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0); // block until bytes can be written
                System.out.println("bo :)");
                if (sp.openPort()) {
                    System.out.println("Port is open :)");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to open port :(");
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < 12; ++i) {
                    sp.getOutputStream().write(vec[i]);
                    sp.getOutputStream().flush();

                    System.out.println("Sent number: " + vec[i]);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                if(sp.getInputStream() != null){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                        a = sp.getInputStream().read();
                        ric[i]=a;
                        System.out.println("Recived number: " + ric[i]);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
                
                if (sp.closePort()) {
                    System.out.println("Port is closed :)");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to close port :(");
                }
        }
    }                  
    };       
   swingWorker.execute();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JFrameAcquario(null).setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The general answer to this to move the non-static stuff **out** of the main and **into** a constructor. Give that a try. If you have further problems, post a [mre]. Hard code some data for the integer vector.  **General tips:** 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: You have a lot of logic inside your main method.   It shouldnt be like that.    Create methods inside your class, have your vector variables inside your class.   Encapsulate everything in the class, then inside your main, simply create an instance of the class, and call the appropriate method on the class....